# Overflow-X causes line line to render on android using chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css

I am trying to solve an issue where `CSS - overflow-x` causes a line to fade in and fade out for a brief second after each h2. This only happens when the webpage is rendered (visited or refreshed).

This doesn't happen on Chrome or Firefox on the computer. It doesn't happen on Safari on Iphone 8 as well.
The following link contain all of the code: https://jsbin.com/liqodaluwo/edit?html,css,output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `overflow-x` for your Text elements in this case, because the text Elements won't be cutted, so just use `overflow:hidden`;

```css
/* Body */
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font: 16px/1 "Montserrat", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background: #101010;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Global */
li {
  list-style: square;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Gallery */
#gallery,
#gallery-card,
#gallery-music,
#gallery-substance-designer {
  font-size: 0;
  list-style: none;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#gallery li,
#gallery-music li,
#gallery-substance-designer li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 0;
}

#gallery-card li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}

#gallery a,
#gallery-card a,
#gallery-music a,
#gallery-substance-designer a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

#gallery img,
#gallery-card img,
#gallery-substance-designer img {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: auto;
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

#gallery img:hover,
#gallery-substance-designer img:hover {
  transform: scale(0.98);
}

#gallery iframe,
#gallery-card iframe,
#gallery-music iframe,
#gallery-substance-designer iframe {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Card */
.card {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.card-info,
.card-info-center {
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #202020;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.card-info {
  text-align: left;
}

.card-info h2,
.card-info-center h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.card-info p,
.card-info-center p {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.card-price {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}

.card-price p {
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.card:hover .card-info,
.card:hover .card-info-center {
  background: #404040;
}

/* Fade In */
.fade-in {
  animation: animation-fade-in 1s;
}

@keyframes animation-fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/* Desktops & Laptops */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1085px) {

  #global-container,
  #global-content,
  #slideshow {
    width: auto;
  }

  #about-profile,
  #about-profile-text,
  #global-sidebar {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
  }

  .details {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
  }

  .information,
  #sys-req {
    padding: 1px 10px 5px;
  }

  #about-divider {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #00000000 0%, #303030 50%, #00000000 100%);
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 10px 10% 0;
  }

  #slideshow-container {
    display: block;
  }

  #slideshow-summary {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
  }

  #slideshow-summary div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: justify;
    max-width: 380px;
    margin: 0 10px;
  }

  #slideshow-summary img {
    width: 400px;
    max-width: 100%;
  }

}

/* Tablets & Mobile Phones */
@media only screen and (max-width: 625px) {

  /* Hide Navigation */
  #navigation {
    display: none;
  }

  /* Show Navigation Icons */
  #navigation-icons {
    display: block;
  }

  /* Expand Body to fit all content (Navigation Icons bar would otherwise hide content) */
  body {
    padding-bottom: 52px;
  }

  /* Download content resize */
  #download-content {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
  }
.card {
  max-width: 150px;

}
.card-info-center h2 {
    white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>


        <!-- Links -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/img/global/favicon.ico">

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=auto">

        <!-- Title -->
        <title>tet</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- Main Content -->
        <main class="container">
            <section>
                <h1>test</h1>

                <!-- Portfolio -->
                <ul id="gallery-card">
                    <li>
                        <article class="card">
                            <a href="/portfolio/games">
                                <img class="lazyload" src="/img/global/lazyload/card.png" data-src="/img/portfolio/t-games.png">
                                <div class="card-info-center">
                                    <h2>Games aw w dwadaw</h2>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </article>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <article class="card">
                            <a href="/portfolio/2d-art">
                                <img class="lazyload" src="/img/global/lazyload/card.png" data-src="/img/portfolio/t-2d-art.png">
                                <div class="card-info-center">
                                    <h2>2D Art</h2>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </article>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <article class="card">
                            <a href="/portfolio/3d-models">
                                <img class="lazyload" src="/img/global/lazyload/card.png" data-src="/img/portfolio/t-3d-models.png">
                                <div class="card-info-center">
                                    <h2>3D Models</h2>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </article>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <article class="card">
                            <a href="/portfolio/particles/page-1">
                                <img class="lazyload" src="/img/global/lazyload/card.png" data-src="/img/portfolio/t-particles.png">
                                <div class="card-info-center">
                                    <h2>Particles</h2>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </article>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <article class="card">
                            <a href="/portfolio/shaders/page-1">
                                <img class="lazyload" src="/img/global/lazyload/card.png" data-src="/img/portfolio/t-shaders.png">
                                <div class="card-info-center">
                                    <h2>Shaders</h2>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </article>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <article class="card">
                            <a href="/portfolio/environments/page-1">
                                <img class="lazyload" src="/img/global/lazyload/card.png" data-src="/img/portfolio/t-environments.png">
                                <div class="card-info-center">
                                    <h2>Environments</h2>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </article>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <article class="card">
                            <a href="/portfolio/programming/page-1">
                                <img class="lazyload" src="/img/global/lazyload/card.png" data-src="/img/portfolio/t-programming.png">
                                <div class="card-info-center">
                                    <h2>Programming</h2>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </article>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <article class="card">
                            <a href="/portfolio/substance-designer/page-1">
                                <img class="lazyload" src="/img/global/lazyload/card.png" data-src="/img/portfolio/t-substance-designer.png">
                                <div class="card-info-center">
                                    <h2>Substance Designer</h2>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </article>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <article class="card">
                            <a href="/portfolio/music">
                                <img class="lazyload" src="/img/global/lazyload/card.png" data-src="/img/portfolio/t-music.png">
                                <div class="card-info-center">
                                    <h2>Music</h2>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </article>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </main>

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="/js/lazyload.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This solved my issue. Weirdly enough, changing it form overflow-x to just overflow was enough. Thank you for the help Hamid!